# Copy files from package to project root directory using composer

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I'm writing a package for Packagist and I'm facing a problem with Composer. I need to copy a file from my package to the project root after install, but nothing is happening after the package installation.

After reading Composer documentation, I found that I should put a script inside the event post-install-cmd, inside the script section into composer.json file.

So, I added this to my package composer.json file

```
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('vendor/myvendor/mypackage/myfile', 'myfile');\""
        ]
    }
```

To install the package I'm doing

```
$ composer require myvendor/mypackage --dev
```

After the package installation everything seems fine, but the file is not being copied and no error is shown.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md for the documentation of scripts. The most relevant part is:

> Note: Only scripts defined in the root package's `composer.json` are
>   executed. If a dependency of the root package specifies its own
>   scripts, Composer does not execute those additional scripts.

So, you cannot define any scripts in your module. There is a [bug report](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1193) about that, but the maintainer of composer is not a friend of executing the scripts of dependencies

Comment: Ok, but, what is the purpose of this 

`"post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],`
in the laravel composer.json file? https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/composer.json

Comment: Have a look at the linked documentation ;) It's run when using `create-project`

Answer (score -2):

You can install this composer plugin to achieve your purpose:
https://packagist.org/packages/markocupic/composer-file-copier-plugin

If configured, the plugin listens to Composers `post-install-cmd` and `post-update-cmd` events and copies files or entire folders from your package to the filesystem.

Configuration is made under the [`extra`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#extra) key inside the composer.json of your package.